# Vue.js performance: avoid parent component re-rendering when the list of children components changes

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, svg, vuejs2

Working on a component listing thousands of items with v-for directive, I got performance issue: updating some items cause re-rendering of the parent component.

We can took an example: a bar chart that color the bars around the client's cursor

```js
Vue.component("BarChart", {
  props: ["data", "width"],
  data() {
    return {
      mousePositionX: null
    };
  },
  template: `
<div class="bar-chart">
  <div>Chart rendered: {{ new Date() | time }}</div>
  <svg @mousemove="mousePositionX = $event.x" :style="{width: width}">
    <bar
      v-for="bar in bars"
      :key="bar.id"
      :x="bar.x"
      :y="bar.y"
      :height="bar.height"
      :width="bar.width"
      :show-time="bar.showTime"
      :colored="bar.colored"
    ></bar>
  </svg>
</div>
  `,
  computed: {
    barWidth() {
      return this.width / this.data.length;
    },
    bars() {
      return this.data.map(d => {
        const x = d.id * this.barWidth;
        return {
          id: d.id,
          x: x,
          y: 160 - d.value,
          height: d.value,
          width: this.barWidth,
          showTime: this.barWidth >= 20,
          colored: this.mousePositionX &&
            x >= this.mousePositionX - this.barWidth * 3 &&
            x < this.mousePositionX + this.barWidth * 2
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("Bar", {
  props: ["x", "y", "width", "height", "showTime", "colored"],
  data() {
    return {
      fontSize: 14
    };
  },
  template: `
<g class="bar">
  <rect
    :x="x"
    :y="y"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    :fill="colored ? 'red' : 'gray'"
  ></rect>
  <text v-if="showTime" :transform="'translate(' + (x + width/2 + fontSize/2) + ',160) rotate(-90)'" :font-size="fontSize" fill="white">
    {{ new Date() | time }}
  </text>
</g>
`
});

const barCount = 30; // to display the bars time, set barCount <= 30

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data: Array.from({
        length: barCount
      }, (v, i) => ({
        id: i,
        value: randomInt(80, 160)
      })),
      width: 795
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 160px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.config.devtools = true;
  Vue.config.productionTip = false;
  Vue.filter("time", function(date) {
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[1].slice(0, -1)
  });

  function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
</script>
<div id="app">
  <bar-chart :data="data" :width="width" />
</div>
```

We can see components re-rendering thanks to the time values displayed, that are updated only when the corresponding component is rendered.

When items (Bar) color are updated, only updated items are re-rendered.
But, **and this is the problem**, the parent (BarChart) is also re-rendered at each cursor movement, even if no items changed.

For bar chart with 30 bars it could be ok.
But if you display a large number of bars, the time spent re-rendering the parent component is too great and cause heavy performance loss.

Look at the same example with 1500 bars:

```js
Vue.component("BarChart", {
  props: ["data", "width"],
  data() {
    return {
      mousePositionX: null
    };
  },
  template: `
<div class="bar-chart">
  <div>Chart rendered: {{ new Date() | time }}</div>
  <svg @mousemove="mousePositionX = $event.x" :style="{width: width}">
    <bar
      v-for="bar in bars"
      :key="bar.id"
      :x="bar.x"
      :y="bar.y"
      :height="bar.height"
      :width="bar.width"
      :show-time="bar.showTime"
      :colored="bar.colored"
    ></bar>
  </svg>
</div>
  `,
  computed: {
    barWidth() {
      return this.width / this.data.length;
    },
    bars() {
      return this.data.map(d => {
        const x = d.id * this.barWidth;
        return {
          id: d.id,
          x: x,
          y: 160 - d.value,
          height: d.value,
          width: this.barWidth,
          showTime: this.barWidth >= 20,
          colored: this.mousePositionX &&
            x >= this.mousePositionX - this.barWidth * 3 &&
            x < this.mousePositionX + this.barWidth * 2
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("Bar", {
  props: ["x", "y", "width", "height", "showTime", "colored"],
  data() {
    return {
      fontSize: 14
    };
  },
  template: `
<g class="bar">
  <rect
    :x="x"
    :y="y"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    :fill="colored ? 'red' : 'gray'"
  ></rect>
  <text v-if="showTime" :transform="'translate(' + (x + width/2 + fontSize/2) + ',160) rotate(-90)'" :font-size="fontSize" fill="white">
    {{ new Date() | time }}
  </text>
</g>
`
});

const barCount = 1500; // to display the bars time, set barCount <= 30

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data: Array.from({
        length: barCount
      }, (v, i) => ({
        id: i,
        value: randomInt(80, 160)
      })),
      width: 795
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 160px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.config.devtools = true;
  Vue.config.productionTip = false;
  Vue.filter("time", function(date) {
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[1].slice(0, -1)
  });
  function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
</script>
<div id="app">
  <bar-chart :data="data" :width="width" />
</div>
```

For 1500 bars, Vue Devtools clearly shows that the time spent re-rendering the parent component is too great (~278 ms) and is causing performance issues.

[image]

So, is there a solution to update child components, which depends of parent's data (like cursor position), and avoid the unnecessary updates of parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties are very useful in Vue...but not always. There are some traps also....

Generating new array with completely new set of objects every time mouse moves is one of them. Because of new array whole `BarChart` component must re-render (and new array every 0.X seconds is also not free).

Solution is to minimize the data changes...in this case with watchers.

```js
Vue.component("BarChart", {
  props: ["data", "width"],
  data() {
    return {
      mousePositionX: null,
      bars: []      
    };
  },
  template: `
<div class="bar-chart">
  <div>Chart rendered: {{ new Date() | time }}</div>
  <svg @mousemove="mousePositionX = $event.x" :style="{width: width}">
    <bar
      v-for="bar in bars"
      :key="bar.id"
      :x="bar.x"
      :y="bar.y"
      :height="bar.height"
      :width="bar.width"
      :show-time="bar.showTime"
      :colored="bar.colored"
    ></bar>
  </svg>
</div>
  `,
  computed: {
    barWidth() {
      return this.width / this.data.length;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    data: {
      handler: function() {
        this.bars = this.data.map(d => {
          const x = d.id * this.barWidth;
          return {
            id: d.id,
            x: x,
            y: 160 - d.value,
            height: d.value,
            width: this.barWidth,
            showTime: this.barWidth >= 20,
            colored: false
          }
        });
      },
      immediate: true
    },
    mousePositionX: {
      handler: 'updateBarsColor'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateBarsColor(x) {
      this.bars.forEach(bar => {
        bar.colored = x &&
          bar.x >= x - this.barWidth * 3 &&
          bar.x < x + this.barWidth * 2
      })
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("Bar", {
  props: ["x", "y", "width", "height", "showTime", "colored"],
  data() {
    return {
      fontSize: 14
    };
  },
  template: `
<g class="bar">
  <rect
    :x="x"
    :y="y"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    :fill="colored ? 'red' : 'gray'"
  ></rect>
  <text v-if="showTime" :transform="'translate(' + (x + width/2 + fontSize/2) + ',160) rotate(-90)'" :font-size="fontSize" fill="white">
    {{ new Date() | time }}
  </text>
</g>
`
});

const barCount = 1500; // to display the bars time, set barCount <= 30

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data: Array.from({
        length: barCount
      }, (v, i) => ({
        id: i,
        value: randomInt(80, 160)
      })),
      width: 795
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 160px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.config.devtools = true;
  Vue.config.productionTip = false;
  Vue.filter("time", function(date) {
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[1].slice(0, -1)
  });

  function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
</script>
<div id="app">
  <bar-chart :data="data" :width="width" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE** - additional question (from comments)

> Ok, it works. But I'm surprised that the BarChart still re-render (you see time changing). This not cause trouble for performance?

After some thought I come to a conclusion that the reason why `BarChart` component is re-rendering every time seemingly for no reason is because of the way the component is passing props to a `Bar` child. In your original (and my 1st) example `BarChart` is "destructuring" the bar config object into separate props. That way, the `BarChart` component is dependent on each property of the config object and needs to re-render every time any property on any object in the array is changed (in order to update child props)

Way to fix this is by passing whole object into `Bar` component. See my second example which is even faster (`BarChart` is not re-rendering at all)

```js
Vue.component("BarChart", {
  props: ["data", "width"],
  data() {
    return {
      mousePositionX: null,
      bars: []      
    };
  },
  template: `
<div class="bar-chart">
  <div>Chart rendered: {{ new Date() | time }}</div>
  <svg @mousemove="mousePositionX = $event.x" :style="{width: width}">
    <bar
      v-for="bar in bars"
      :key="bar.id"
      :config="bar"
    ></bar>
  </svg>
</div>
  `,
  computed: {
    barWidth() {
      return this.width / this.data.length;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    data: {
      handler: function() {
        this.bars = this.data.map(d => {
          const x = d.id * this.barWidth;
          return {
            id: d.id,
            x: x,
            y: 160 - d.value,
            height: d.value,
            width: this.barWidth,
            showTime: this.barWidth >= 20,
            colored: false
          }
        });
      },
      immediate: true
    },
    mousePositionX: {
      handler: 'updateBarsColor'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateBarsColor(x) {
      this.bars.forEach(bar => {
        bar.colored = x &&
          bar.x >= x - this.barWidth * 3 &&
          bar.x < x + this.barWidth * 2
      })
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("Bar", {
  props: ["config"],
  data() {
    return {
      fontSize: 14
    };
  },
  template: `
<g class="bar">
  <rect
    :x="config.x"
    :y="config.y"
    :width="config.width"
    :height="config.height"
    :fill="config.colored ? 'red' : 'gray'"
  ></rect>
  <text v-if="config.showTime" :transform="'translate(' + (config.x + config.width/2 + fontSize/2) + ',160) rotate(-90)'" :font-size="fontSize" fill="white">
    {{ new Date() | time }}
  </text>
</g>
`
});

const barCount = 1500; // to display the bars time, set barCount <= 30

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      data: Array.from({
        length: barCount
      }, (v, i) => ({
        id: i,
        value: randomInt(80, 160)
      })),
      width: 795
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 160px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.config.devtools = true;
  Vue.config.productionTip = false;
  Vue.filter("time", function(date) {
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[1].slice(0, -1)
  });

  function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
</script>
<div id="app">
  <bar-chart :data="data" :width="width" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can of course write a much more effective `updateBarsColor` function by passing also the prev value instead of doing `forEach` but I'll leave that part for you...

Comment: Ok, it works. But I'm surprised that the `BarChart` still re-render (you see time changing). This not cause trouble for performance? Can we conclude the problem was just that we built new big array each ~10ms?

Comment: I'm not saying I am an expert on Vue internals. I'm not sure why it is working...`Bar` component props are just primitive values, not objects, right ?
Anyway you would be surprised how much time it takes to allocate and **make reactive** a new array with 1500 objects ...